# How to create and print sales ticket with images and rich text

Tags: c#

Good afternoon:

I'm stuck like two weeks with the creation of sales tickets and their printing.

I know there is a good example with RawPrinterHelper but this does not allow to modify fonts (type, size, bold, color, etc).

On the other hand I've seen iTexSharp but I do not know how to print tickets with a long VARIABLE and give the page cut in a thermal (sequence Escape).

Same as above, how would you do it with StringFormat, PrintDocument or similar?

In conclusion, what would be the best option?

Thank you

regards

Comment: Are you trying to build a web page? A desktop app? What kind? WPF? WinForm? UWP?

Comment: A desktop application where a sales ticket is generated and sent from there to print.

Comment: I use C #, Entity Framework and SQL Server Express.